Weak convergence of $f(x,e^{itx})$
This is the desired result (what I want to prove):
$$f(x,e^{itx})\overset{t\to\infty}{\rightharpoonup}\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{|z|=1}\frac{1}{z}f(x,z)dz \tag{1}$$
Given that $f\in C([a,b]\times\{e^{i\varphi}\ |\ \varphi\in[ 0,2\pi)\})$
. I used $\rightharpoonup$ to denote weak convergence.
I saw this idea from a question on MSE and I want to prove the better version of it. In an answer to that question, Gerd provided a proof for the case $f(x,\sin(tx))$ (instead of $f(x,e^{itx})$), so I tried using his argument but I failed to apply Weierstrass Approximation Theorem because the constructed polynomials are identically equal to $0$, as shown below:
($\ g(x)$ is a sample function)
$$\lim_{t\to\infty}\int_{a}^{b}g(x)e^{itnx}dx=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{in\varphi}d\varphi\int_{a}^{b}g(x)dx=0\ , n\in\mathbb{N}\backslash\{0\} \tag{2}$$
With that being said, how should result $(1)$ be proved?
Note
Originally, the integral equality being equivalent to $(1)$ should look like this:
$$\lim_{t\to\infty}\int_{a}^{b}f(x,e^{itx})dx=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{a}^{b}\int_{0}^{2\pi}f(x,e^{i\varphi})d\varphi dx \tag{3}$$
I just used contour integration and the idea of weak convergence to simplify to its core.

By (say) the Stone–Weierstrass theorem, the continuous function $f$ on the compact set $[a,b]\times\{e^{i\varphi}\ \colon \varphi\in[ 0,2\pi)\}$ can be uniformly approximated by polynomials. So, without loss of generality, $f(x,y)=x^m y^n$ for some nonnegative integers $m,n$. Then the right-hand side of (2) is
$$1(n=0)\int_a^b dx\, x^m,$$
which, by the Riemann–Lebesgue lemma, coincides with the left-hand side of (2). $\quad\Box$

So the values of those integrals don't matter as long as we have RHS=LHS, right? In my mind, it was like we approximated the integral of $f(x,y)$ with a bunch of "useless" $0$s .

@QuýNhân : I don't understand your comment at all.

Sorry, I was confused about how the theorem works, now I understand what went wrong for me. By the way, just out of curiosity, I'm really interested in these oscillatory integrals, do you have any idea about their name (or references)?

Got it. Thanks.
